# FCM Swipe Notification

Tags: android, push-notification

The Google has good documentation on handling FCM notifications. But anywhere in the docs I cannot find out how to handle "notification message" (not data message) when the app is in background and user just swipes it off. In this case the app does not gets any message.

Is there a way to handle this use case? Or we assume that since the user has swiped of the notification from the system tray the user does not cares about it and hence app does not have to do anything for that message and that message is lost permanently?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct, if the user swipes it away the app does not get notified and unless you run a NotificationListener service

Comment: Oh Thanks. So will this service gets called even when my app is in background and I send a "notification message" which usually shows up only on system tray?

Comment: Sad. It says it only works for api level 18 but my app needs to support from 15.